# How to sort datagridview columns programmatically

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I am being asked to sort columns on a VB.Net created DataGridView. It's not my code but I'm trying to help. Here is part of the code:

```
Try
        Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT  * FROM Manpower WHERE LogOutTime IS NULL AND LogInDate = #" & dateToday & "# ORDER BY CustomerName"

        Dim myDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSelect, myWorkforceConnection)

        myCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter)

        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Exit Sub
    End Try

    If myDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No records found.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    dgvManpower.DataSource = myDataTabl

    dgvManpower.Columns("ID").Visible = False

    dgvManpower.Columns("EmployeeName").Width = 175
    dgvManpower.Columns("EmployeeName").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
    dgvManpower.Columns("EmployeeName").HeaderText = "Employee Name"
```

When I run the application I'm not able to sort on the EmployeeName column. The Microsoft documentation claims that a Glyph will be added to the column header but that doesn't appear either.  How can I get the column to be "sort-able" ?

Comment: you would not sort the DGV but typically bind to a DataView, then just change that (programmatically).  the code shown doesnt sort, just sets it up to sort if the user clicks on that column

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in your code that would stop sorting.

Check the datagridview settings in the IDE, and ensure that datagridview has  `Enabled=True`, and `ColumnHeadersVisible=True`.

Then click a column header and see what happens.

Comment: I thought I had all the IDE properties on the DGV set properly but I missed the Enabled = True. It works now.